# How can I use my own application bar with tilt effec?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, wptoolkit

For my Windows Phone 8 application, I'm implementing my own application bar (I can't use the application bar provided by the system). Everything is working fine, but I have one big problem: the tilt effect for menu items!

I've tried to used the tilt effect provided by the WP toolkit, but it doesn't look like the original one. So how can I use the exact tilt effect by the system application bar in my own application bar ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your own app bar is not Tiltable Item.
you can get the TiltEffect.cs file from this link:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Tilt-Effect-Sample-fab3b035

and then you should add your own app bar to the TiltableItems in TiltEffect's Constructor, some like this:

```
    static TiltEffect()
    {
        // The tiltable items list.
        TiltableItems = new List<Type>() { typeof(ButtonBase), typeof(ListBoxItem), };
        TiltableItems.Add(typeof(Border));
        TiltableItems.Add(typeof(TiltEffectAbleControl));
        UseLogarithmicEase = false;
    }
```